# How to get token balance from Metamask using new window.ethereum provider

Tags: javascript, ethereum, metamask

Below code is using new `window.ethereum` provider, not web3.
What is the way of connecting/interacting with ERC20 token, ERC721 contracts?

```
const contractAddress = "0x2A65D41dbC6E8925bD9253abfAdaFab98eA53E34"; // address of the token contract
const wallet = '0x821e28109872cad442da8d8335be37d317d4f1e7'; // address of which you want to get the token balance
let contract = new ethereum.contract(minABI).at(contractAddress);
let userBalance = await contract.balanceOf(wallet);
consolve.log(userBalance);




let minABI = [
// balanceOf
{
"constant":true,
"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],
"name":"balanceOf",
"outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],
"type":"function"
},
// decimals
{
"constant":true,
"inputs":[],
"name":"decimals",
"outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],
"type":"function"
}
];
```

Error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ethereum.contract is not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

The best way of interacting with a contract *is* by using ethers.js or web3. Please don't try to use the raw `window.ethereum` object, as its behaviour might depend on the wallet. The Metamask docs themselves instruct you to use web3 or ethers.